# AVMetadataItem with nil CommonKey

Tags: ios, swift3, swift4

I am working on an App that, among others, reads Audio files from the the file sharing folder and I am trying to get as many information from the file using the metadata associated.

There are some values from the [AVMetadataItem] with keys that I can read using a loop like

```
    for metadataItem in audioAsset.metadata{
        if metadataItem.commonKey == AVMetadataKey.commonKeyArtist{
           print("artistName IN METADATA \(metadataItem.value)")
    }
```

But on the array there some others with nil value -> Common Key = nil & value = 1/2

I am specially interest on that one because it gives me the track number. The audio has been edited with itunes so i was expecting a matching AVMetadataKey.

I have also realised that if I print the key value i get something like "TPE1" which stands for the Artist. Is there any documentation about that?

-Is there anything missing?

-Which is the best way to edit metadata?

-On the event i have a UIViewController that edits the file, Can I add metadata values?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have written a class that returns the metedata for .mp3, .alac and .aac files. Since the metadata associated is different they need to be retrieved differently.

See the result [here](https://github.com/reimond/AudioMetadataItem/blob/master/MetadataItem.swift)

The only thing is init the class with a URL and It will manage the process and handling errors.